# python threading - a problem

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib

I can't figure out the problem in this code.

```
class Threader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, url, host):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.url = url
        self.host = host

    def run(self):

        print self.url # http://www.stackoverflow.com            

        with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(self.url)) as u:
            source = u.read()

        print "hey" # this is not printing!

        source = self.con()

        doc = Document(source)

        self.queue.put((doc, self.host))
```

When I run this code, `print self.url` succesfully outputs the url but `print "hey"` is not working. So basically, (I believe) there is something with contextlib which is blocking the code. I also tried the conventional `urlopen` method without using `contextlib`, but it doesn't work either. Furthermore, I tried `try` - `except` but the program doesn't raise any error. So what may be the problem here?

Comment: Then obviously one of the other computations between those `print` statements block. There are only two of them (at this level of abstraction, anyway), so one single print statement could help you reduce the guessing...

Answer (score 2):

Your Code doesn't work, I have taken the liberty to adapt it a bit (imports, also it doesn't know about Document and self.con), and make it compatible with python2 (that's what I use here at the moment) - it works:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
import threading, Queue, urllib2, contextlib

class Threader(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue, url, host):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.url = url
        self.host = host

    def run(self):
        print self.url
        with contextlib.closing(urllib2.urlopen(self.url)) as u:
            source = u.read()
        print "hey"

if '__main__'==__name__:
    t = Threader(Queue.Queue(), 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', '???')
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

EDIT: works also with "with" and contextlib

Comment: ahh yeah, self.con was a method I was using. But still after trying to connect it was not raising an error like "con not found" so something is really blocking when using contextlib

Comment: Btw, urllib2.urlopen does not work either. I really don't know why :S

Comment: Well, I know ideally your code should work. I have many other functions (in some other applications) which use either urllib.open or with but in this instance it just stops working.

Comment: can you: (1) use the url in a browser on this machine and (2) ping e.g. google.com from the console your starting the python process?

Comment: then I don't know. Above code runs fine here, with (of course) a small latency before the "print "hey"" :-(

Comment: Thanks for the efforts :) I guess I'll try something different

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem persists with only using urllib, the most probable cause is that the url you are trying to open does not response.

You should try to

1. open the url in a browser or a simple web client (like wget on linux)
2. set the `timeout` parameter of `urllib2.urlopen`

Comment: are you using a proxy to access the internet ? try opening an url from outside your browser

Comment: Well, I am trying to connect from the terminal using import urllib2, and it just works fine. I have also another threading application which uses urllib, that works fine, too. I really can't figure out why this problem is happening with this code...